# how to import printed C console to node red

Tags: exec, node-red

i'm using Dragino rpi Lora transceiver C code on the pi to send and receive packets to the Arduino .

the C code is working perfectly where it prints the received packets and the Signal to noise ratio and the timestamp ,
 but i want to use it in node red . 
how can i import the received packet from the C console to node red ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [node-red-node-daemon](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-daemon) for long running processes that run until stopped and receive input via standard in and send results by standard out.

[image]