# execNode in NodeRed doesn't execute a while 1 statement

Tags: node-red

I'm running an exec node to run C code to send and receive data via Lora.

The code runs perfectly without a while 1 loop.

If I put a while true loop it will keep running but won't work.
The while 1 is used to read data every second.

I tried using daemon exec node also bigExec but none worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to import printed C console to node red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450772/how-to-import-printed-c-console-to-node-red)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the process doesn't ever exit (which is what I assume you mean by having a while 1 loop) then the daemon node is the correct answer.

As long as your application prints it's output to stdout or stderr and includes a new line at the end of each output it will send a new message for each line of output. You might need to ensure that stdout is properly flushed, you can do this by adding `fflush(stdout);` after the printfs e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;
    int max = 0;

    if (argc == 2) {
        max = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    while (1) {
        if (max) {
            if (++i > max) {
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        printf("helloWorld\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(2);
    }

}
```

The exec node will wait until the process exits before sending a message so is not not what you need.

Comment: i tried it it gives me 
"Command not running" even though on the terminal it works

Comment: Have you looked in the logs or attached debug nodes to stderr and return code ports

Comment: message payload - 2 
command in daemon node : 
sudo  /home/pi/Desktop/rpi-lora-tranceiver-master/dragino_lora_app/dragino_lora_app

thanks a lot for your help
as i said before the command runs on terminal

Comment: The command should be `sudo` and the arguments should be `/home/pi/Desktop/rpi-lora-tranceiver-master/dragino_lora_app`

Comment: the command shows that it's running in the flow 
but it isn't printing anything or doing anything . 
without the infinite loop it worked .. but how can i make it work with it ?

Comment: Then your C app is not flushing stdout after each printf